# How to sort a gridview table in ascending order without clicking the header

Tags: c#, gridview, gridview-sorting

My table always sorts in ascending order only when I click the header. Is there a way I can use the sort direction property of the sorting method to automatically sort the table?
Thanks to the stack overflow excellent programmers.
Below is the existing suggested solution, but it seems it was not properly spelt out. i.e like how to call the method from the event handler assigned for the gridview's OnSorting event..

```
private void GridViewSortDirection(GridView g, GridViewSortEventArgs e, out SortDirection d, out string f)
{
    f = e.SortExpression;
    d = e.SortDirection;

    //Check if GridView control has required Attributes
    if (g.Attributes["CurrentSortField"] != null && g.Attributes["CurrentSortDir"] != null)
    {
        if (f == g.Attributes["CurrentSortField"])
        {
            d = SortDirection.Descending;
            if (g.Attributes["CurrentSortDir"] == "ASC")
            {
                d = SortDirection.Ascending;
            }
        }

        g.Attributes["CurrentSortField"] = f;
        g.Attributes["CurrentSortDir"] = (d == SortDirection.Ascending ? "DESC" : "ASC");
    }

}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sort

Comment: Why don't you solve it on a database level, return CurrentSortDir field in a ascending or descending order from database(I guess you are getting data from database [Order by CurrentSortDir ASC] ) :)

Comment: @Slai Thanks! But this situation is a bit different from what was explained in your reference page.

Comment: @billy_56 I am getting my data from db of course, but is there a way of doing this from the application?

Comment: @billy_56 Thank you, I think I I have resolved to do it from the db. using "order by 'fieldname' asc"

Comment: @LibertyCrownInfotech It is best way, you are skiping any kind of complications in your app, everything is resolved on database layer :) and can you please vote up if I helped you? :)